# RewriteCond HTTP:Accept-Language all subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Currently I have added the following code to the .htaccess. This code detects browser language and forwards the Spanish visitors to /es/

When users with a Spanish language visit mysite.com they are automatically send to mysite.com/es/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(es.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/images/.*)  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/es/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /es/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works fine, but does not work with subfolders. For example if the same user visits mysite.com/page/ they are not send to mysite.com/es/page/

How can the code be change so that is works with all subfolders?

Like it is possible with www redirects

```
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !site.com
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

if you visit site.com/page/test/ you will be automatically redirected to www.site.com/page/test/ Yet something like this does not seem to work with language to go from www.site.com/page/test/ to www.site.com/es/page/test/

Answer (score 0):

If your layout is such that there are subfolders with content, not a web application, then you would need such a .htaccess file in each of the subfolders. The same file placed in the es directory should do the trick.

As for differentiating between Spain-Spanish and Peru-Spanish, you can try es-ES and es-PE.

Comment: Thank you. With a blog that has over 1000+ subfolders (each page/post) that would be an impossible task.

Comment: In that case, try putting those rules in the main Apache configuration file, like httpd.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-available/default .

Comment: Is there a way to do this without root access? I hoped it was possible to say in .htaccess to RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} for root and all subfolers to root and all subfolders.  Like it is possible with www redirects 
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !site.com
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]  if you visit site.com/page/test/ you will be automaticly redirected to www.site.com/page/test/  Yet something like this does not seem to work with language to go from www.site.com/page/test/ to www.site.com/es/page/test/

Comment: Well domains and folders are treated differently, so while something like that may work for rewriting sub/domains, it won't work for folders or subdirectories. `.htaccess` is a local override - it is only valid for that directory it is placed in. When someone visits that directory, the .htaccess in the document root is not processed. So AFAIK your options are to place this .htaccess file in every subdirectory you want the rewrite to happen, or have a global rule in the VirtualHost section of your conf file.